# Menu (Submenu) Needs To Be Dynamic Instead Of Static

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, menu

I have a purely .css driven menu. Currently, I have the flyout on the sub-sub menu appearing at 180px. This obviously doesn't work because as soon as menu text that exceeds 180px is entered, the submenu text is overlayed with the sub-submenu text (In the example, Highlighting Products > Entertainment Centers USA shows the problem).

The spot in the .css where I have explicitly stated the 180px width is below. I need it to be dynamic, i.e. the desired behavior is for the flyout to align with the right side of the first level vertical menu regardless of the first level submenu's width.

```
/* -- Appearance of second vertical dropdown menu unhovered (submenu of first level vertical menu) -- */
.rmenu li ul li:hover ul li a {
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 5px;
    background: #e8dec7; /*background color for submenu hovered text*/
    color: #51db29;  /* this is the color of the sub-sub menu text. I made the color (#51db29) 'unusual' as an example. Should be changed to something less jarring (of course) */
    word-wrap: break-word;
    min-width:100px;
    position: relative; left: 180px; top: -35px;  /* display 3rd level to the right (180px) */  /*left: 180px*/

}
```

The jfiddle is here:

http://jsfiddle.net/9c8wcxju/4/

Many, many thanks.....

Comment: You need to include the desired behaviour of the menu. Dynamic is very vague and your current fiddle doesn't do anything

Comment: The fiddle works perfectly for me and displays the problem as described. I've called another user and he's able to view the fiddle as well. Perhaps moving the center vertical divider to the left will help? I've further described the desired behavior above. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure the link is correct? I am using Mac FF, nothing happens when i hover over the beige bar. Same thing on chrome

Comment: Yes, it's correct. i'm using PC/Chrome. If all you see is a beige bar and no menu text, try to either maximize the window or 'grab' the center vertical bar between the html and the css and move it to the left. I had that issue with another fiddle and that's how I got it to display. Sorry it isn't more straight forward, but I don't know any other way to do it. Thank you for taking a look.

Comment: To simplify the issue, I made http://jsfiddle.net/9c8wcxju/4/ from yours

Comment: Thank you for doing that. I've changed the URL in the question.

Comment: There are numerous issues. You should make the entire sub menu ul position absolute and not target the anchors individually. Give each level ul a class so you can target it  easier.

Comment: I appreciate the comments re: not targeting the anchors and adding classes/IDs for clarity. I've tried every combination of relative/absolute, including making all of the Subs absolute, but with no result addressing the alignment issue. Virtually all examples of pure CSS menus I see have some sort of fixed width _(like my 180), but there has to be a way to accomplish my objective. I've spent loads of time on this and am at my wits end. Thanks again.

Comment: Right now I am unsure what you are trying to achieve. Do you just want a menu where there are 3 levels and each sub level flies out to the right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have simplified everything down and made this for you. You can expand on it and do what you want with it. I couldn't really work with yours, ended up deleting most of the css.

As you can see I have added class to each level of the sub-menu so it is easier to target. What I have created is what I think you wanted, I hope this puts you on the right track.

http://jsfiddle.net/9c8wcxju/5/

```
.rmenu ul li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}

.rmenu ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.rmenu li a {
    display:block;
    min-height: 35px;
    line-height: 35px;
    font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #000000;
    background-color: #e8dec7;
    text-decoration: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.rmenu li:hover a {
    background: #d6cbb0;
}
.rmenu .hidden {
    display: none;
}

.rmenu .level_1 > li {
    float: left;
}
.rmenu .level_1 > li a {
    padding: 0 10px;
}

.level_1 > li:hover .level_2,
.level_2 > li:hover .level_3 {
    display: block;
}

.level_2 {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}
.level_3 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This looks really good and solves the problem. I also rewrote the css as you suggested, though your solution is more elegant, so I'm about to put yours in place. I really appreciate the time you've put in. Now I have to make the responsive portion work...:) Have a great day!